# Extract type from Prisma 5 client

Tags: typescript, prisma

On Prisma 4, the generated client file (`node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts`) contained the types for our models with this syntax:

```
/**
 * Model User
 * 
 */
export type User = {
  id: number
  name: string | null
}

/**
 * Model Post
 * 
 */
export type Post = {
  id: number
  user_id: number | null
  content: string
}
```

which was very useful, because with a node script, we copy/pasted those types to a MD file to generate documentation.

Now on Prisma 5, the following code is generated to the prisma client file:

```
/**
 * Model User
 * 
 */
export type User = $Result.DefaultSelection<Prisma.$UserPayload>
/**
 * Model Post
 * 
 */
export type Post = $Result.DefaultSelection<Prisma.$PostPayload>

...

export type $UserPayload<ExtArgs extends $Extensions.Args = $Extensions.DefaultArgs> = {
    name: "User"
    objects: {}
    scalars: $Extensions.GetResult<{
      id: number
      name: string | null
    }, ExtArgs["result"]["user"]>
    composites: {}
  }

...

export type $PostPayload<ExtArgs extends $Extensions.Args = $Extensions.DefaultArgs> = {
    name: "Post"
    objects: {}
    scalars: $Extensions.GetResult<{
      id: number
      user_id: number | null
      content: string
    }, ExtArgs["result"]["post"]>
    composites: {}
  }
```

the problem is that those types are not "human-friendly" and we can't copy/paste them to our MD files for documentation.

Is there a way to generate plain simple types for the models like the ones generated in Prisma 4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe so due to the prisma client extensions feature that allows these type to be modified. But it does have the same info in there in `$PostPayload['scalars']`. It's a bit more work to pull out, but you can still do it easy enough.